# Как добавить несколько фрагментов в один контейнер?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Пытаюсь добавить несколько фрагментов в один контейнер, но в результате получается так, как если бы добавлял без цикла первый фрагмент. Где ошибка?

```
 if (radioArray != null) {
                for (Radio r : radioArray) {
                    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    RadiosFragment radiosFragment = new RadiosFragment(this, r);
                    mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, radiosFragment);
                    Log.d("debug", r.getGenre());
                    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
```

Comment: а если открыть и закрыть транзакцию вне цикла?

Comment: Пробовал! Все то же самое...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался: у меня во фрагменте был RecyclerView. Когда я добавлял фрагменты на активность - первый прокручивался до конца и все. Задиссеблил скролл на списке и вставил скролл родительским лэйаутом для контейнера с фрагментами.

Answer (score 0):

Это смотря в какой `layout` вы добавляете свой фрагмент. Фрагмент всего лишь кусок того же лейаута только со своими заморочками.

Если `R.id.main_container` представляет собой `FrameLayout` - то вы стопочкой друг на друга сложите свои фрагменты, они перекроют друг друга и будет доступен/виден только последний.

Если же `R.id.main_container` это `LinearLayout` - то фрагменты выстроятся друг за дружкой горизонтально или вертикально в зависимости от ориентации `LinearLayout`

Comment: <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

Comment: Понятно. У вас все фрагменты имеют дефолтный тег `null`, попробуйте давать им разные теги.

Comment: mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, radiosFragment, r.getGenre());
Проблема та же...